Understanding php-fpm resources config
I currently have a stack with PHP-FPM and Nginx running on ECS EC2.
After observing some metrics, I noticed that the memory and CPU usage of my stack is low.
However, when I tried reducing my tasks from 13GB to 9GB, I saw a significant increase in connections caused by PHP-FPM. Could someone explain why this happens, even though my previous resource usage was low, allowing room for adjustments?
www.conf:
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 150
pm.start_servers = 4
pm.min_spare_servers = 4
pm.max_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_requests = 500

ECS Task Config:
TASK_MEMORY="9216"    

TASK_MEMORY_RESERVATION="8192"

old values
TASK_MEMORY="13516"    

TASK_MEMORY_RESERVATION="12288"

[PHP-FPM]
[Container-CPU]
[MEMORY-RSS]
